# Convert screen coordinate to OpenGL vertex float point

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 to draw free form path when user touch the screen.
according to lots of samples in order to make an object i need to define vertex using float values of x,y,z in an array. 
i just stumbled upon a problem that i can't define these float numbers from screen coordinate.
i have made a Line class based on the triangle object class provided by android sample.

for now, in my GLSurfaceView class i use onTouchEvent method then in my Renderer i use this formula to convert screen coordinate to float point.

```
float lineCoords[] = new float[6];
    lineCoords[0] = (float) (mPreviousX * 2.0 / WIDTH - 1.0);
    lineCoords[1] = (float) (mPreviousY * -2.0 / HEIGHT + 1.0);
    lineCoords[2] = 0.0f;
    lineCoords[3] = (float) (x * 2.0 / WIDTH - 1.0);
    lineCoords[4] = (float) (y * -2.0 / HEIGHT + 1.0);
    lineCoords[5] = 0.0f;
```

basically the formula followed the glOrtho array but the result is not satisfying because it seems like there's a vertical mirror at the center of the screen that draws the path on the right side if i touch on the left side and also the other way around.

so, what is the **best way to convert touched screen coordinate to those float x,y,z**? (assuming z stay 0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could juste use `gluUnProject` or get the modelview and projection matrix and invert the calculation, going from screen to space coordinates.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml

Comment: I'm using this method now 

public static int gluUnProject (float winX, float winY, float winZ, float[] model, int modelOffset, float[] project, int projectOffset, int[] view, int viewOffset, float[] obj, int objOffset) 

but i have no idea how should i put the float[]model and float[]project. from opengl sample android there's no such things like that i guess

Comment: You just have to get the matrix with glGetIntegerv and glGetDoublev, just look at the documentation it's quite clear